# Conditional comments for IE not working

Tags: html

I'm trying to include an IE7-only stylesheet using a conditional comment:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Description">
  <link href="/static/styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/static/styles/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/static/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <!-- [if IE 7]>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/ie7.css">
  <![endif]-->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/static/images/layout/favicon.png">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I have a Windows 7 virtual machine (running on VirtualBox) and I'm using the developer's tools in IE9 to switch the browser mode to IE7. Nothing in the referenced stylesheet is applied to the page. I'm loading this stylesheet after all others, I'm using `!important` on everything, and I've triple-checked the file name and path, but the styles are still not being applied. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: I am not sure but perhaps the IE9 browser mode is not quite equal to IE7.  Have you tested it on an IE7 virtual machine to rule out this factor?

Comment: You have a space in this line: `<!-- [if IE 7]>`, don't remember if the syntax allows that to be there? Possibly not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a space

```
<!--RIGHT HERE[... remove that one
```

before:

```
<!-- [if IE 7]>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/ie7.css">
 <![endif]-->
```

after:

```
 <!--[if IE 7]>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/ie7.css">
  <![endif]-->
```

not sure if thats it though

Comment: Holy crap. That was it. I had no idea that the space mattered. Never would have caught that. Thanks!